# Python pull Excel table

Tags: python, excel

I'm looking for a way to pull a python table (listObject) from excel.

I've got a fairly good system going using `xlwings sheet.ragnge('tableName')` going, only issue I have with this is that there's no straight forward way to return the table columns other than finding the range and grabbing the row above.

This is no issue for me but my boss would like to know if there's a more reliable solution to find and refer to a table via it's name, perhaps using named ranges or (see below). As just to keep the code 
 reliable and streamlined for others to use.

Current code for values:

`wb = xlwings.Book(excelFile)
tableObj = sht.range(table)
values = tableObj.value`

[image: Excel table name]

Comment: it would be helpful to know what u r trying to achieve overall. it is possible that some other library could deliver what u want

Comment: I've been given an Excel book with tables spread out here and there. I'm looking for the most robust way to pull those tables and export them into a SQL database. xlwings is the best I found but i can't find a straightforward way to pull column headers.

Comment: i know openpyxl can help with that, picking ranges column names and all. is it possible to share one table that i can possibly play with?

Comment: Yeah sure, they're pretty simple tables. How should I go about sharing it with you?

Comment: google drive or some other secure means u have